# HDD on SATA I and SSD on SATA II

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata

Recently my laptop has gone slower and I'm planning to buy a SSD.
I don't have that much money to buy a 1TB. So I'm looking for a 120GB SSD and keep my old HDD.

So here are the questions:

1. I need to replace laptop's ODD (which is connected to a SATA I port) with the HDD. Does it affect HDD speed?
2. The SSD will be connected to a SATA II port. Does SATA II offer enough speed for a SSD?
3. Can I expect noticable improvement in overall laptop speed?

Comment: Do you mean "SATA I/II" as in port #1/#2, or do you mean "SATA II" as in SATA version v1/v2?

Comment: I mean SATA version I and SATA version II

Answer (score 2):

In broad terms, & assuming you have only a single SATA I & SATA II port, giving you no real choice in the matter…

An SSD on SATA II will still be leaps ahead of the old HDD on the same bus, even if it's running at half its potential speed.

If you've no alternative, putting the old HD on SATA I will at least work, if not at any great speed. If the HD is slow anyway [5200 rpm drive], you *may* not even notice the difference.

In rough terms, SATA I is 1.5Gb/s, SATA II is 3Gb/s & SATA III is 6Gb/s.
An SSD may shift data at 5Gb/s peak, so you're missing out on the ultimate performance, but an HD is going to only be moving at maybe 1.5Gb/s anyway. [There are drives that will break this at both extremes, this is a very very rough estimate].

So long as you don't immediately fill your SSD to 80% capacity - which will bottleneck the heck out of it - you should see a much better performace.

I would still go for a bigger SSD. They're nowhere near as expensive as they used to be. These days I'd consider 256 to be 'minimum', 512 starts to get 'comfortable'.

Comment: Just installed a hardware info software.Under "SATA AHCI Controller" section it says that supported interface speed is "Gen 3 6.0Gbps".Does it mean that the laptop's supported SATA is SATA III?Maybe I've not realized the SATA version correctly?and SATA II is actually HDD controller speed?

Comment: Possibly. If it is, then win/win.